# Write automatic title at save_post (infinite loop)

Tags: actions, save-post

I want to write the post title with the content of a custom field `$sentence_number`, this way:

```
add_action('save_post', function ($title, $post_id) {
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    if ($post_type == 'sentence') {
        $sentence_number = get_field('sentencia_no', $post_id);
        wp_update_post($post_id, [
            'post_title'   => $sentence_number
        ]);
    }
}, 10, 2);
```

But I get this error:

**Uncaught Error: Maximum function nesting level of '200' reached, aborting!**

How should I do it for avoid the loop? Thank you.

Comment: You use wp_update_post inside your action callback. It calls save_post so you get infinite loop ;)

Comment: Understood. Thank you. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way, You need to use filter hook **wp_insert_post_data**
So the code should be like

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'set_post_title_with_field_value' );

```
function set_post_title_with_field_value( $data )
{
    if ($data['post_type'] == 'sentence' ){
        $sentence_number = get_field('sentencia_no', $data['ID']);
        $data['post_title'] = $sentence_number;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

You need to add this code into theme's functions.php.
So try the code and let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: It works perfect! thank you very much. My final code is a slightly different but essentially is the same as you proposal: https://bitbucket.org/aitormendez/superbiajuridico/commits/dfa751a87133f78d3abc69147672cd4e28f6757b